# Add Container Div to every Gutenberg-Block in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm using the Gutenberg editor and the Bootstrap CSS framework.
Per default, there is no container or something like this around a Gutenberg block.

Some of the blocks have an `alignwide` and `alignfull` option to add something like a container around them. These options are good for cover images or paragraphs.

But an headline block has (per default) not such an option.

And I would love to add an extra checkbox to every Gutenberg block to toggle an extra container `div` around the it. Not just a class.

I found something to add an extra style to every Gutenberg blog: https://www.billerickson.net/block-styles-in-gutenberg/

Here's the code from there:

```
wp.domReady( () => {

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/heading', {
        name: 'default',
        label: 'Default',
        isDefault: true,
    } );

    wp.blocks.registerBlockStyle( 'core/heading', {
        name: 'alt',
        label: 'Alternate',
    } );

} );
```

It works well, to give the block an additional class/style.
But it doesn't wrap something around the block.

Is there any option to add something like an container toggle (adds `div` with `.container` class) to a block?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If someone also need this (like me) nowadays WordPress already has another filter that is easier to implement called `render_block`

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/render_block/

here is an example

```
    function wporg_block_wrapper( $block_content, $block ) {
        if ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/paragraph' ) {
            $content = '<div class="wp-block-paragraph">';
            $content .= $block_content;
            $content .= '</div>';
            return $content;
        } elseif ( $block['blockName'] === 'core/heading' ) {
            $content = '<div class="wp-block-heading">';
            $content .= $block_content;
            $content .= '</div>';
            return $content;
        }
        return $block_content;
    }

    add_filter( 'render_block', 'wporg_block_wrapper', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to add a wrapper to a core block by using a **block filter** but it isn’t that simple and I would not recommend to add a modification to all core blocks. A much simpler and more flexible solution would be to add a **custom wrapper block** that accepts **InnerBlocks** (from wp.editor) as childs (you can even define which blocks to accept) and set support for align options (in the toolbar) and an anchor/id in the block settings sidebar. The class for the wrapper will be automatically created from your block name. 
You can then use your custom wrapper block only if you need it and put every other block inside of it (a headline block for example).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably gonna have to use the blocks.getSaveElement to wrap the element

https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/developers/filters/block-filters/#blocks-getsaveelement

```
function modifyGetSaveContentExtraProps( element, blockType, attributes ) {
    return (
        <div className = 'heading-wrapper' >
            { element }
        </div>
    );
}


wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveElement',
    'slug/modify-get-save-content-extra-props',
    modifyGetSaveContentExtraProps
);
```

Comment: It works in the frontend but in the editor it still show the default rendering.

Comment: This is because you are editing the save function with the hook ```'blocks.getSaveElement'```. Maybe by now there is a function to edit the edit function.