# Alter rendering of core Gutenberg-block in WordPress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56527970/1091772) to modify core block rendering by using the `getSaveElement` filter. The code is as follow:

```php
function modifyGetSaveContentExtraProps( element, blockType, attributes ) {
    return (
        <div className = 'heading-wrapper' >
            { element }
        </div>
    );
}


wp.hooks.addFilter(
    'blocks.getSaveElement',
    'slug/modify-get-save-content-extra-props',
    modifyGetSaveContentExtraProps
);
```

That works in the frontend, the rendering is altered, but in the block editor it still uses the default block rendering.

How can I have the block editor also reflect/refresh the changes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    function modifyBlockEdit( editComponent ) {
         return (
            <div className = 'heading-wrapper' >
              { editComponent }
           </div>
     );
   }

     wp.hooks.addFilter(
       'blocks.blockEdit',
       'slug/modify-blockEdit',
       modifyBlockEdit
      );
```